# Unmet dependency while installing PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, postgresql

I am trying to install Postgresql on my brand new Ubuntu 15.04 installation and run into this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 9.4.1-1.pgdg12.4+1) but 9.4.1-1.pgdg14.04+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here are the steps I normally do to install PostgreSQL:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 pgadmin3
```

This works fine on my 14.04 LTS release. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
apt-mark showhold
```

to see the list of held packages and use:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>
```

to un-hold them. After his remove the package causing problem using `sudo apt-get remove`

Comment: `apt-mark showhold` doesn't output anything. It doesn't fail, but it seems to be empty.

Comment: Try to unhold/remove `libpq5 `. Re-install and then remove if the former did not work

Comment: Please upgrade your answer. Describe what has been successful.